# Site thumbnails not showing when sharing a url

Tags: facebook, url, share, thumbnails, canonical-link

After upgrading Joomla and the template for a website the thumbnails stop appearing when sharing a article url.
Example from the debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Falbonsai.pt%2Findex.php%2Feventos%2Fatividades%2F76-atividade-de-junho-2014

The problem appears to be in the canonical link, if I remove this line all works great

```
<link href="http://albonsai.pt/index.php/eventos/atividades/76-atividade-de-junho-2014" rel="canonical" />
```

I have other websites with this code and none has the same problem.
Could Anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/lamb-full.jpg">
```

exist in your content.
You could check this facebook tutorial about the usage:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects

Comment: Already tried several plugins to insert the open graph tags and still the same problem.

Comment: This [official facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) may help you investigate the problem

Comment: gives an error about missing tags, but I have other sites without them and they work fine.

Comment: in other sites it may get the photo from the content, without og tags you won't be sure that it will work.